# Do we say space of 5 years or timing of 5 years

Tags: word-usage, exam-questions

Edit:
I think space is the right answer but some of my collegues told me the the answer should be timing
I googled space and timing of time but i only found space-time and 4d and unrelated things like that.

The question:

> The project will be carried out in a ...... of 5 years
>
> A. Part
>   B. Place
>   C. Space
>   D. Timing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on oxford dictionary
The answer is space

Link: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/space

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I answered it timing and that was my only mistake on our exam...  +1

Comment: But I think it's kind of wrong..! Because it said that `An interval of time (often used to suggest that the time is *short* considering *what has happened* or *been achieved in it*)` Note that it tells us that space refers to something that *has happened* or *been achieved!* but in the OP question, it didn't happen yet! Also, 5 years isn't a *short* time!

Comment: Like.. Once I entered the supermarket, my money disappeared in space of 2 hours... So I think [timing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/timing) is the correct one! Just read about it and you'll notice **`A particular point or period of time when something happens.`**

Comment: The thing is you cant say timing of 5 years. Sonething feels off about it The structure of the sentence would be wrong.

Comment: But you can say space of 5 years although it should mean short time but it's O.L. I doubt that the one who made the exam knows that space of time is used for a short time .But maybe he meant that the project should be finished in 20 years but it will be finshed in 5 so time will shorter. Just a thought....

Comment: Maybe it does feel a little bit off but timing is a logical answer if we looked up its definition carefully... But, I think both answers should be correct because it's a very tricky & independent question anyways to be put in the English exam. And it doesn't really matter since it's just experimental. Good luck in the math tomorrow. 

Comment: Good luck to you too